# Filtrar elementos de array en javascript recursivamente

Tags: javascript, array, recursión

tengo un problema para filtrar un array de objetos para la interfaz de un e-commerce.

La API me suministra un array de objetos con la informacion de cada producto, cada producto puede pertenecer a 1 o mas categorias de la sigiente forma:

```
const products = [
{
  name: 'product',
  // ...
  categories: [
    {
      name: 'name',
      slug: 'slug',
    },
    {
      name: 'name 1',
      slug: 'slug-1',
    },
    // ...
  ],
},
// Otros productos cpn igual estructura
];
```

Mi intencion es poner un filtro de etiquetas para el usuario y al momento de seleccionar una categoria se quiten los otros productos del array y queden solo los productos que tengan dicha categoria.

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia o aporte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero poder ayudarte.
Normalmente usamos la función `filter()` en los array para obtener un resultado determinado con ciertos criterios, esta función espera un `return true` para agregar el objeto resultado, de ser `return false` pues no agrega el objeto al resultado final.

Entonces vamos a filtrar el array `products` por categoría, pero categoría es otro array, entonces debemos volver a filtrar el array de categorías, sí el filtro de categorías devuelve un resultado mayor a 0 entonces devolvemos `true` en el filtro de productos.

```
// variable que tiene el valor del nombre de la categoria a filtrar
var valueFilter = 'nombre de la categoría a filtrar';
// vamos a llamar a la función filter del array products para filtrar los productos
const result = products.filter (
  product => {
    // una vez dentro queremos que los productos filtrados sean por categoria entonces recuperamos el atributo categories y ejecutamos la función filter.
    const resultCategory = product.categories.filter(category => category.name == valueFilter);
    // luego vamos a verificar el resultado del filtro de categorias, si es diferente de undefined y el resultado es mayor a 0 entonces retornamos el objeto al resultado total con un true, si no un false para no agregar el objeto.
    if (resultCategory != undefined  && resultCategory.length > 0)
      return true;
    return false;
  });
```

Espero haberte ayudado, suerte, por favor lee los comentarios.
La función puede hacerse más pequeña pero la explayo para poder explicarte el "por qué".

Recordar que la función `filter()` no devuelve `undefined` entonces no es necesario que verifiques si es distinto de `undefined`.

Comment: Sabia como filtrar los productos, pero ni idea de como hacerlo con las categorias... muchas gracias

Comment: Sí, hasta es suficiente con realizar dentro del filtro de productos `product.categories.filter(category => category.name == valueFilter).length > 0` ya que esa es la operación lógica que devuelve `true` o `false`. Acortando el código tal vez a una sola linea.